# Updated core data concurrency documentation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, concurrency

The only (and most recent) results I'm finding about best practices are here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdConcurrency.html

However, the very top of the page says,

"Important: Best practices for concurrency with Core Data have changed dramatically since this document was written; please note that this chapter does not represent current recommendations."

Where can I find more current documentation for concurrency with core data?

Comment: This is not Apple documentation, but you may find it helpful: http://quellish.tumblr.com/post/97430076027/a-real-guide-to-core-data-concurrency

Comment: One billion up votes for this question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best discussion is now under 'Concurrency' within the [`NSManagedObjectContext` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/NSManagedObjectContext.html).

My summary:

Thread confinement is still required. The big changes introduced by iOS 5/OS X v10.7 were that contexts can now have other contexts as parents and can manage their own serial queues.

Changes are automatically migrated from children to parent upon a save. That's now what save means. Only if your parent is the persistent store are you actually committing to disk.

So all that stuff about synchronising by notifications is what Apple doesn't want you to follow. All of those mechanisms are still available but Apple has pulled the most common patterns directly into the framework.

Comment: "Thread confinement is still required." This is not the case at all, and thread confinement has been obsolete for some time. Queue confinement has been the recommended paradigm for quite a while.

Comment: On the contrary, Apple has always explicitly said: "Note: You can use threads, serial operation queues, or dispatch queues for concurrency. For the sake of conciseness, this article uses “thread” throughout to refer to any of these." When talking about Core Data, thread confinement and queue confinement are synonyms, with the former being the preferred phrasing — accurately or otherwise.

Comment: The documentation you are referring to is outdated, and was written well before queue confinement was introduced. This is why at the very top of the document you are quoting it states "Best practices for concurrency with Core Data have changed dramatically since this document was written; please note that this chapter does not represent current recommendations.". Thread confinement and queue confinement are different paradigms for CD concurrency - they are NOT synonyms.

Comment: Thread confinement only allows access to a context created on that thread. Queue confinement allows access from any thread, and the context is free to manage however many threads it wants. Operations performed on the context are managed through the queue by the context. Queue confinement and thread confinement are *not synonymous*.

Comment: @quellish you don't seem to understand the topic. That document clearly says: **in this document, thread confinement and queue confinement are synonymous terms**. I then said: **thread confinement as described in that document is still a requirement**. Everybody here understands that a thread is not a queue. It's not in the slightest bit relevant if you're able to follow the conversation.

Comment: I understand the topic quite well. The key point is "in this document". That document *does not cover* queue confinement as we know it now. The document does not describe queue confinement as it is today at all. Queue confinement was introduced in 2011, if you look at the revision history for that document you will see that it was not updated with anything relevant to queue confinement since then other than the disclaimer about best practices changing. Thread confinement is obsolete. The concurrency guide does not reflect that.

Comment: @quellish the current, most up-to-date `NSManagedObjectContext` documentation still uses queue and thread interchangeably under its 'Concurrency' section. The two are still synonyms. Or else the third sentence: "You should not, therefore, initialize a context on one thread then pass it to a different thread." means that you can't use queues at all with contexts. So either I'm right and they're synonyms **in this very limited context** or you're right and queues may not be used.

Comment: No, it does not use them interchangeably, and in fact is explicitly differentiates between the two: "thread (**or** serialized queue) confinement" , etc. It then goes on to detail the differences between thread confinement and queue confinement when explaining the 3 different constant values that can be passed to `initWithConcurrencyType:`. You will note that CONFINEMENT is described as different from the two QUEUE based constants. It is also called out as being a legacy value, and described as implementing queue confinement.

Comment: This is obviously a comprehension issue at your end; I don't see this conversation progressing constructively. The context of the sentence I quoted quite explicitly shows that Apple is still using thread and queue confinement interchangeable. Fuller quote: "You should not, therefore, initialize a context on one thread then pass it to a different thread. Instead, you should pass a reference to a persistent store coordinator and have the receiving thread/queue create a new context derived from that".

Comment: You seem to be confused by the portions of the documentation that are referring to the thread or queue of the *caller*, not the context. In that case, thread and queue are being used interchangeably - but that is only in reference to *thread confinement*. Core Data queue confinement, which was introduced in 2012, does not have those concerns.

Comment: "in this document, thread confinement and queue confinement are synonymous terms." That's not what it says. It says: "You can use threads, serial operation queues, or dispatch queues for concurrency. For the sake of conciseness, this article uses “thread” throughout to refer to any of these." The document is still talking about *thread confinement* exclusively. The document was never updated for *queue confinement*.

Comment: (+1) It's a little unfortunate the document you point to directly links to the (insanely annoying) one the OP is talking about. It's very frustrating! Thank you though, I will use the basic `NSManagedObjectContext` documentation.

Answer (score 3):

The Core Data Programming Guide has been updated for iOS 9/OS X El Capitan. See https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Concurrency.html.

I also found [WWDC 2014 session 225 What's new in Core Data](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/#225) (at 22:50) very helpful in understanding both current and historic concurrency methods.

Answer (score 2):

Thread confinement has been obsoleted. You can see this in the header for `NSManagedObjectContext`:

```
NSConfinementConcurrencyType        = 0x00,    /* this option is obsolete and not recommended for new code. */
```

When a context is created with `-init`, it calls the initializer `-initWithConcurrencyType:` with the argument `NSConfinementConcurrencyType`. This is the threading model described in the Core Data Programming Guide section on concurrency, that has been obsolete and not recommended for some time. In the words of one Core Data engineer "It just didn't work.".

Unfortunately that Core Data Programming Guide has not been updated to describe the current recommended best practices for concurrency and other advancements.
But hey, at least it's not telling you to use locking!

The [Incremental Store Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/IncrementalStorePG/Introduction/Introduction.html) has been updated recently. It describes how to implement an NSIncrementalStore, and in doing so does a very good job of explaining some of Core Data's internals. For example, it describes what a fault is and how faults are fired far better than the Core Data programming guide ever did. The Core Data release notes for the past [several years](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/ios/releasenotes/DataManagement/RN-CoreData/index.html) have included some updated information about best practices, and there are several tech notes that are relevant to Core Data.

The best information in the last several years has been the yearly "What's New In Core Data" sessions at WWDC. For concurrency, you should check out these WWDC sessions:

[WWDC 2011 What's new in Core Data on MacOS X](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/#315). The MacOS X session was a little more detailed than the iOS session.

and

[WWDC 2012 Core Data Best Practices](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/#214)

I would encourage you to use the "Feedback" button on the Core Data Programming Guide pages, or file a radar bug asking for the documentation to be updated.

Answer (score 0):

The guide that I've been following is here: http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/07/multi-context-coredata/

Even though it was written in 2012 it still seems to match what i've seen currently being used. It helps you set up a main parent context with NSMainQueueConcurrencyType, multiple background contexts with NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType, and also has a background writer context that has the persistent store.

Xcode 6 and Yosemite also seem to have an improvement in core data debugging: http://oleb.net/blog/2014/06/core-data-concurrency-debugging/. This was useful in understanding how to use performBlock at the right places.